# Own standard MatLab command

Tags: matlab, command-line, command, colormap

I tried to create my own colormap in MatLab and so far it worked well.
I just took the `parula.m` from `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017b\toolbox\matlab\graph3d`, put it in my working directory, edited the numbers in the matrix and named it `myColormap.m`.
Then I was able to stuff like

```
>> myColormap
```

which gives me the RGB-array back.
I also could define a `colormap` via

```
>> cmap = colormap(myColormap(20))
```

to use it for plots in the following.

**Now my question is:** How can use this commands from every directory? Because for now they only work, if I have the `myColormap.m` in my working directory.
Do I have to put the `myColormap.m`-file in a certain directory or put the command `myColormap` in any list of commands or what do I have to do to access it from anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB has a list of folders in which it searches for functions. These folders include those that contain MATLAB's built-in functions. If you want to be able to call your own function from anywhere; you need to add the path where that function can be foudn to this list.

One option is to use the [`addpath`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addpath.html) command. I usually like to specify that the folder I am adding should go to the end of the search path list, so if there happen to already be functions sharing the same name in other folders in the list, those will take precedence.
Example:

```
addpath('c:\my\folder\', '-end');
```

A second option is to use the graphical user interface to do this. The path set dialog tool can be opened by running [`pathtool`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pathtool.html) or by navigating to it from the menu bars of MATLAB: go the Home tab and, in the Environment section, click Set Path.

Note that changes you make using this strategy will only work during the current MATLAB session. If you exit MATLAB and run it again later, you will have to add the path again! It is possible to also make the new path addition permanent; if you use `pathtool` there should be query asking about this.